# Why i cannot display element of mine list? - java

Tags: java, json, list, gson

i have problem with my list. My goal is to make a JTree from my json list. To do it i convert my json where i have my patients to list. But i cannot even display the name of mine patient. Maybe my code make my problem clearer. I would be grateful for any suggestion!

My patient class:

```
public class Patient {

private String name;
private String surname;
private String pesel;


public Patient(String name, String surname, String pesel) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.pesel = pesel;

}

public String getName(){return name;}
public void setName(String name){this.name = name;}

public String getSurname(){return surname;}
public void setSurname(String surname){this.surname = surname;}

public String getPesel(){return pesel;}
public void setPesel(String pesel){this.pesel = pesel;}
}
```

My patientList: 
(This method works, when i am using it to convert medicine json to medicine list i have no problem)

```
public List<Patient> FromJsonToArray1() throws IOException {
    String patientsJson = initArray("Patients.json").toString();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    java.lang.reflect.Type patientsListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Patient>>() {}.getType();
    List<Patient> patientArray = gson.fromJson(patientsJson, patientsListType);
    return patientArray;
}
```

And this is my function to show name of mine patient.

```
 public  void jtreecreator() throws IOException {
    List<Medicine> medicineList = FromJsonToArray();
    List<Patient> patientList = FromJsonToArray1();
    medicinesDataMethods medicinesdatamethods = new medicinesDataMethods();
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Patients");
    Patient c = patientList.get(0);
    Medicine d = medicineList.get(0);
    DefaultTreeModel treeModel = new DefaultTreeModel(root);
    JTree tree = new JTree(treeModel);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(tree);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,c.getSurname());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, d.getName());
}
```

And after call this function it display d.getName(), but c.getSurname() didnt work.

Its my json where i store my patients:

```
[
  {
    "Pesel": "1111",
    "Surname": "Walker",
    "Name": "Johny "
  },
  {
    "Pesel": "11111",
    "Surname": "Walker1",
    "Name": "Johny1 "
  }
]
```

After debug, i find out that my list which is created in FromJsonToArray1() has objects of patients but values of name, surname and pesel are null. :C

Comment: If you debug `jtreecreator()`, do you see correct values in `c` and `d` objects?

Comment: I see something like models.medicine@123123

Comment: You can expand the object and check the value of `name`

Comment: how? I didnt do it?

Comment: You can google how to inspect objects for IDE you are using

Comment: But i didnt check value here? JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,c.getSurname());? It works for d object.

Comment: Ok i used some debug, and it looks like objects in array have null in name, surname and pesel parameter

Answer (score 0):

Issue is attribute names in class and json do not match. You can modify `Patient` class like

```java
class Patient {

    @SerializedName("Name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("Surname")
    private String surname;

    @SerializedName("Pesel")
    private String pesel;

    // getters and setters, constructor, etc. here
}
```

Comment: I solved this with exchange list on set collection, but thx for answer